# tomcat7-maven-plugin startup always fails in maven project, but when I directly use tomcat7, it's normal

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-tomcat-plugin

I see the mistake, but I don't know how to correct it

[image: tomcat7]

[image: mistake]

Comment: Ultimate edition or community?

Comment: Ultimate edition